# How do you add content to a grid cell without HTML?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I am trying to fill the empty field (column 1, row 2) with standard content (i.e. "NOT AVAILABLE"). I was not available to come up with any appropriate solution within CSS - tried a few approaches with CSS selectors, but without any luck.

How do I achieve this, without using JS or adding an empty element in the HTML source? The reason I don't want to use other technologies is because we cannot alter the original HTML content.

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.itemA{
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.itemB{
  grid-column: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="itemA">Content A</div>
    <div class="itemB">Content B</div>
    <div class="itemB">Content C</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS Grid, CSS pseudo-elements are treated as grid items. (This is the equivalent behavior of [pseudo-elements in flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS), which are flex items.)

Therefore, using CSS alone, you can achieve your goal:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid::before {
  content: "NOT AVAILABLE";
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.itemA {
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.itemB {
  grid-column: 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="itemA">Content A</div>
  <div class="itemB">Content B</div>
  <div class="itemB">Content C</div>
</div>
```